# not allowed to send mail from my own account?! DNS lookup / SPF

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, spf, gmail, dns-zone

I give training and therefor i have a gmail account 
(linked to my weebly website www.serenewarrior.nl)

Sometimes I get a Delivery Status notification (below) saying I am not allowed to sent mail and I need to contact the postmaster of MY website.

I am an absolute no no in these things and need to know how and where to fix it. Can someone guide me through?

Is it fixable in gmail settings?

The response was:

550 2a00:1450:4864:20::444 is not allowed to send mail from serenewarrior.nl. Please see http://www.openspf.net/Why?scope=mfrom;identity=info@serenewarrior.nl;ip=2a00:1450:4864:20::444

An SPF-enabled mail server rejected a message that claimed an envelope sender address of info@serenewarrior.nl.

An SPF-enabled mail server received a message from mail-wr1-x444.google.com (2a00:1450:4864:20::444) that claimed an envelope sender address of info@serenewarrior.nl.

The domain serenewarrior.nl has published an SPF policy, however, an error occurred while the receiving mail server tried to evaluate the policy:

Maximum void DNS look-ups limit (2) exceeded.
What should I do?

The domain serenewarrior.nl will have to fix the problem. You can contact the serenewarrior.nl postmaster and tell them about the error message you received.

Answer (score 3):

The SPF record for your domain is not set correctly. You need to fix that with your domain registrar's control panel, not in the Gmail settings. It currently is:

> serenewarrior.nl. IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:185.182.56.13 a:spf.spamexperts.axc.nl a:mail-wm0-f47.google.com a:mail-wm0-f51.google.com -all"

To use your own domain with Gmail / G Suite you need to follow the instruction found here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en

The most relevant instruction from that help page is that in the SPF record for your domain you need to authorise Gmail's servers to send email on your behalf by adding `include:_spf.google.com` rather than the specific google.com servers (a:mail-wm0-f47.google.com a:mail-wm0-f51.google.com) you have currently listed.

Comment: This will fix the problem. You shouldn't try to list individual mail servers, as Google has thousands of them.

Answer (score 1):

Following HBruijn's answer you can get mail from Gmail pass SPF. But that's not the only thing that may cause problems, like the error reported by the `openspf.org/Why`:

> The domain `serenewarrior.nl` has published an SPF policy, however, an
>   error occurred while the receiving mail server tried to evaluate the
>   policy:
>
> *Maximum void DNS look-ups limit (2) exceeded.*

Let's investigate your current SPF policy a little, piece by piece with the additional DNS lookups made.

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:185.182.56.13 a:spf.spamexperts.axc.nl 
 a:mail-wm0-f47.google.com a:mail-wm0-f51.google.com -all"
```

1. Only `ip4` and `-all` can be directly evaluated from the SPF policy record alone. Then...
2. `a` causes an additional lookup for `serenewarrior.nl. IN A` (or `AAAA` case this is an IPv6 address).
3. `mx` causes an additional lookup for `serenewarrior.nl. IN MX`, causing steps 4-7.

   ```
   serenewarrior.nl.   IN   MX   20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
   serenewarrior.nl.   IN   MX   10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
   serenewarrior.nl.   IN   MX   30 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
   serenewarrior.nl.   IN   MX   30 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
   ```
4. `ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. IN A`
5. `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. IN A`
6. `ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. IN A`
7. `ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. IN A`
8. `a:spf.spamexperts.axc.nl` adds `spf.spamexperts.axc.nl. IN A` (10 addresses, 0 for `AAAA`).
9. `a:mail-wm0-f47.google.com` adds `mail-wm0-f47.google.com. IN A` (1 address, 0 for `AAAA`).
10. `a:mail-wm0-f51.google.com` adds `mail-wm0-f51.google.com. IN A` (1 address, 0 for `AAAA`).

**This is why you should use `ip4` and `ip6` mechanisms** whenever possible:

- `a` can be replaced using the IP address (`serenewarrior.nl. IN A 199.34.228.59`)
- It seems that so-called *spam experts* doesn't utilize `include` mechanism that would allow them to use CIDR notation in their SPF records, so this part you cannot change. Listing the IP addresses or blocks would make them unable to update the list. (However, if you don't send mail from their servers, you can remove it. This we can't evaluate for you.)
- Google doesn't use the same servers for incoming and outgoing mail, so the `mx` can be removed altogether. This and the rest can be replaced with `include:_spf.google.com`.

**Resulting SPF policy record would be:**

```
"v=spf1 ip4:199.34.228.59 ip4:185.182.56.13 a:spf.spamexperts.axc.nl include:_spf.google.com -all"
```

This does one nested lookup for `a:spf.spamexperts.axc.nl` and 4 for Gmail as it has 3 additional includes.